# Server with dynamic ip?

Tags: redirect, ip

I was wondering if it was possible to have a redirect to a server that is under dynamic ip. I'm using www.no-ip.com to redirect to my dynamic ip. Since my ip changes everyday, I have to manually update the ip info on no-ip.com. Is there another way to set up a server under a dynamic ip or is that not possible at all?

Answer (score 3):

With Dynamic DNS ( http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-free/), you can set up a static URL that redirects to your IP address. With DynDNS Updater (You can download from dyndns site for Mac or Windows), it automatically sends your current dynamic IP when it changes so that the URL "follows" your IP, keeping it static.

Answer (score 2):

I use [zoneedit](http://zoneedit.com) (free for 1 domain) for DNS hosting, and they have an HTTP api that you can call to set your IP. So I have my dhcp daemon call this using an 'exit hook' when the IP changes.

My server runs ubuntu and I have this in /etc/dhcp3/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/nsupdate:

```
if [ "$interface" = "eth0" ]; then

if [ "$reason" = "BOUND" ] || [ "$reason" = "REBIND" ] || [ "$reason" = "RENEW" ]; then

wget -O - --http-user=<redacted> --http-passwd=<redacted> 'https://dynamic.zoneedit.com/auth/dynamic.html?host=<redacted>' > /var/log/dhclient.log

fi

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

While this will be closed and doesn't belong on SO, no-ip has a client that will automatically  update your info just like DynDNS and all the other solutions.

You install it on your box and it will detect when your internet facing IP address changes and automatically update your no-ip info. No manual steps required.

[No-IP Client](http://www.no-ip.com/downloads.php)